# calcular distancia entre dois pontos em php

Tags: php, lógica

estou fazendo um projeto e preciso calcular a distância em quilômetros(KM) usando a latitude e a longitude achei uma função em php porem quando vou pegar o resultado e comparar com a do google ele da diferente, a função que encontrei foi essa:

```
    function calcDist($lat_A, $long_A, $lat_B, $long_B) {

    $distance = sin(deg2rad($lat_A))
        * sin(deg2rad($lat_B))
        + cos(deg2rad($lat_A))
        * cos(deg2rad($lat_B))
        * cos(deg2rad($long_A - $long_B));

    $distance = (rad2deg(acos($distance))) * 69.09;

    return $distance;
}
```

A função me retorna :

> 0.15712674480811772

Porem a distancia correta seria :

> 260 metros

Comment: Sua fórmula está equivocada, você está tentando aplicar a lei dos senos em calculo geodésico. Essa fórmula funciona bem num plano mas num esferoide ela não funciona eu conheço duas fórmulas para calcular a distancia geográfica a Haversine e A Projeção Geodésica. A Haversine é mais precisa porém tem que entrar com a correções diferenciais para distancias terrestres devido as variações de raio da terra então eu fiz esse [exemplo](https://repl.it/repls/HarshAnguishedServer) usando projeção geodésica com fator de correção de 15%. Não coloquei como resposta devido a imprecisão inerente a fórmula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!function_exists('distancia')) {
    function distancia($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2)
    {

        $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
        $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
        $lon1 = deg2rad($lon1);
        $lon2 = deg2rad($lon2);

        $dist = (6371 * acos(cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * cos($lon2 - $lon1) + sin($lat1) * sin($lat2)));
        $dist = number_format($dist, 3, '.', '');
        return $dist;
    }
}
```